# Missing type Mono.Web.Util.RoleManagerSectionMapper in empty project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono, xsp

I've set up the latest Mono (3.4.1) and the latest XSP from Git and compiled them. `mono -V` prints the following:

```
main@zombie# mono -V
Mono JIT compiler version 3.4.1 (master/89e0b25 Fri May 16 18:52:44 CEST 2014)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen
```

Now I've created a sample ASP.NET MVC project in Visual Studio 2013. It contains some basic pages. I've chosen to use the very simple example without authentication stuff. On Windows, it runs. On Mono, the following error appears:

```
System.TypeLoadException
Could not load type 'Mono.Web.Util.RoleManagerSectionMapper, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): mscorlib.
Exception stack trace:
    at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Type:internal_from_name (string,bool,bool)
    at System.Type.GetType (System.String typeName, Boolean throwOnError) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at Mono.Web.Util.SettingsMapping.get_MapperType () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at Mono.Web.Util.SettingsMapping.MapSection (System.Object input, System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at Mono.Web.Util.SettingsMappingManager.MapSection (System.Object input, System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at Mono.Web.Util.SettingsMappingManager.MapSection (System.Object input) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName, System.String path, System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule.Init (System.Web.HttpApplication app) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at System.Web.Configuration.HttpModulesSection.LoadModules (System.Web.HttpApplication app) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
    at System.Web.HttpApplication.InitOnce (Boolean full_init) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

What I tried is to search the whole project for `RoleManagerSectionMapper` - no results.

Comment: did you compile mono from master (git) as well? (it's ambiguous if you only got XSP from git, or mono too)

Comment: I recompiled Mono from tarball in Version 3.4.0. Same error appears.

Comment: I found this page, but I don't know if this is what I'm searching for. I don't think so. http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET_Settings_Mapping

Comment: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=19839 looks like there was a bug and it was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Possible answers by the following

@Andreas
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=19839

@TheWavelength
http://www.mono-project.com/archived/aspnet_settings_mapping/